# Performance of MYSQL "IN"

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm running a MYSQL query in two steps. First, I get a list of ids with one query, and then I retrieve the data for those ids using a second query along the lines of `SELECT * FROM data WHERE id in (id1, id2 ...)`. I know it sounds hacky, but I've done it this way as the queries are very complicated; the first involves lots of geometry and triggernometry, the second one lots of different joins. I'm sure they could be written in a single query, but my MYSQL isn't good enough to pull it off.

This approach works, but it doesn't *feel* right; plus I'm concerned it won't scale. At the moment I am testing on a database of 10,000 records, with 400 ids in the "IN" clause ( i.e. `IN (id1, id2 ... id400)` ) and performance is fine. But what if there are say 1,000,000 records?

Where are the performance bottlenecks (speed, memory, etc) for this kind of query? Any ideas for how to refactor this kind of query for be awesome too. (for example, if it is worth swotting up on stored procedures).

Comment: Why don't you put more details of your query?

Comment: I guess I'm not asking about any particular query; rather just if it is a good idea in principle to use "IN" with a huge parameter list

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Starting from a certain number of records, the `IN` predicate over a `SELECT` becomes faster than that over a list of constants.

See this article in my blog for performance comparison:

- [**Passing parameters in MySQL: IN list vs. temporary table**](http://explainextended.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-in-mysql-in-list-vs-temporary-table/)

If the column used in the query in the `IN` clause is indexed, like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table1
WHERE   unindexed_column IN
        (
        SELECT  indexed_column
        FROM    table2
        )
```

, then this query is just optimized to an `EXISTS` (which uses but a one entry for each record from `table1`)

Unfortunately, `MySQL` is not capable of doing `HASH SEMI JOIN` or `MERGE SEMI JOIN` which are yet more efficient (especially if both columns are indexed).

Comment: This has really helped me out too. Good article.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you extract the ids first? You should probably just join the tables. If you use the ids for something else, you can insert them in a temp table before and use this table for the join.

Comment: Yep, you're probably right. I do the extract first because the extract query is really complicated (lots and lots of maths, some subqueries etc) and my tiny brain couldn't work out how to do the join at the same time.. really just wondering if I should be putting that refactor near the top of my to-do list or not!

Comment: Then you should probably put them in a temp table. That would be simpler than getting them and building the in clause. And has Quassnoi says it would be faster.