# Most efficient way to select lots of values from database

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table with around 2400 'items'. A user will have any arbitrary combination of items from the 2400 item set. Each item's details then need to be looked up and displayed to the user. What is the most efficient way to get all of the item details? I can think of three methods:

- Select all 2400 items and parse the required details client-side.
- Select the specific items with a SELECT which could be a very long SQL string (0-2400 ids)?
- Select each item one at a time (too many connections)?

I'm not clued up on SQL efficiency so any guidance would help. It may help to know this is a web app heavily AJAX based.

Edit: On average a user will select ~150 items and very rarely more than 400-500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best method is to return the data you want from the database in a single query:

```
select i.*
from items i
where i.itemID in (<list of ids>);
```

MySQL queries can be quite large (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html)), so I wouldn't worry about being able to pass in the values.

However, if your users have so many items, I would suggest storing them in the database first and then doing a `join` to get the additional information.

Comment: Would you agree with Anders and say that to select more than 50 items a Join is more beneficial? Also it may be worth noting that the user's items are determined by an external API and can change (slightly) daily.

Comment: @Titus . . . If the data is already in the database, then a `join` is the way to go.  If users are selecting zillions of items, then test to see which is faster.  I don't see why 50 would be the cut-off point.  By the way, the temporary table should have an index on the `id` for it to be optimal.

Comment: I once worked maintaining a database abstraction layer. While it was Oracle and hence had a fixed upper limit on how many items could be in an IN-list, we still saw performance degrade distinctly as we put more items in the list. I don't recall all the details - but we saw this already before we hit ~100 items. So while @Titus mileage might vary, the 50 wasn't grabbed out of thin air. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the users never/rarely select more than ~50 elements, then I agree with Gordons answer.

If it is really plausible that they might select up to 2400 items, you'll probably be better off by inserting the selected ids into a holding table and then joining with that.

However, a more thorough answer can be found [here](http://explainextended.com/2009/08/18/passing-parameters-in-mysql-in-list-vs-temporary-table/) - which I found through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1537685/806549) answer.

He concludes that:

> We see that for a large list of parameters, passing them in a temporary table is much faster that as a constant list, while for small lists performance is almost the same.

'Small' and 'large' are hardly static, but dependent upon your hardware - so you should test. My guess would be that with an average of 150 elements in your IN-list, you will see the temp table win.

(If you do test, please come back here and say what is the fastest in your setup.)

Comment: I would say on average a user would select ~150 items and it would be highly unlikely to select more than 400-500.

Answer (score -1):

2400 items is nothing. I've have a MySql database which has hundreds of thousands of rows and relation and are working perfectly, by just optimizing the queries.

What you must do is, see how long the execution time is for each sql query. You can then optimize each query on its own, trying different querys and measure the execution time.

You can use ex. MySql Workbench, Sequel pro, Microsoft Server management studio or another software for building queries. Also you can add indexes to your tables, which can improve queries as well.

If you need to scale your database up you can use software like http://hadoop.apache.org

Also a great thing to mention is NoSQL (Not-Only SQL). It's a relation-less database, which can handle dynamic attributes and are build for handling large amount of data.

As you mention you could use AJAX. But that only helps the load time of the page and the stress of your web server (Not SQL server). Just ask if you wan't more info or more in-depth explanation.